# "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code" even if not

Tags: discussion, not-properly-formatted-as-code

I am trying to post a question and I can't because I always get this error:

> "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code"

Even if I can see on the preview that all code is clearly identified, that I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to format it.

I also tried with

```
code here
```

and on the preview everything appears correctly.

But I still get this error and I can't post my question...

How can I get rid of this?

Here is my question:

````
Hi,
I have some problem using pyaudio.
I am working on ubuntu 18.04 using python 3.6.7, pyaudio version 0.2.11
and the following dependencies : libportaudiocpp0 portaudio19-dev libportaudio2-dev

basically I am running this:

<pre><code>```python
import pyaudio
import wave

CHUNK = 2048*50
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 3
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "test.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
info = p.get_host_api_info_by_index(0)
numdevices = info.get('deviceCount')
for i in range(0, numdevices):
  if (p.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0,i).get('maxInputChannels')) > 0:
    print("Input Device id ", i, " - ", p.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i).get('name'))

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                 channels=CHANNELS,
                 rate=RATE,
                 input=True,
                 frames_per_buffer=CHUNK, input_device_index=0)

print("* recording")
frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
   data = stream.read(CHUNK)
   frames.append(data)

print("* done recording")
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
</code></pre>

a .wav file is produced but it doesn't contain any sound.
I know my microphone (the one included in the laptop is working (I can skype for example).

here is the output of the script:

>ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1052:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
>
>ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel >map
>
>ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1052:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
>
>Input Device id  0  -  HDA Intel PCH: ALC3228 Analog (hw:0,0)
>
>Input Device id  4  -  sysdefault
>
>Input Device id  5  -  pulse
>
>Input Device id  6  -  default
>
>* recording
>
>* done recording
````

Comment: I don't have any images in my post so I am not sure :Images being interpreted as incorrectly formatted code  is being a good link

Comment: *If none of the duplicates help at all* then you'd need to provide your question body here because without knowing the body of the question there's no way for us to know what's wrong with it

Comment: Firstly, get rid of the `<pre>` and `<code>` wrappers, use the ones provided by SO (4 space indentation or wrapping with triple backticks (\`\`\`), also it looks like the last bit of your question should be formatted as code (the output), that may help

Comment: It seems you were trying to use fenced code blocks, you have  ````python` at the beginning of the block. As Nick said, remove the `<pre><code>` tags, and add the closing ``` to the code-block. An while you are at it, remove the "Hi,", salutations are not considered noise and do not belong in posts. Good luck!

Comment: it seems that the problem was the output. but it's really strange to have an output formatted as code. Is there a way to not format it as code but as blockquotes ?

Comment: You're probably best putting it in blockquotes AND codeblocks, as the formatting for codeblocks is often better for code output than just as text

Comment: @PeterMortensen you probably shouldn't edit the contents of the Markdown in a post reporting a Markdown bug