# Using the code tags causing errors

Tags: support, code-formatting

I've followed [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269565/199965) to attempt to strike out previous erroneous code in [this question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57439314/interrupting-a-function-due-to-an-event-firing). My justification for doing this is that the code example I provided was misleading, however removing it removes context from the comments and answers already provided for future readers.

Unfortunately the result is a "Your code is not properly formatted" error, which I don't appear to be able to bypass at all:

[image]

The code previews correctly as expected, so I expect this is an editor validation issue?

Comment: It's a known issue with the pre code blocks: [“Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code” even if not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388255/7795130). Using the 4-space code blocks or the `\`\`\`` code blocks should fix it.

Comment: @DavyM Well strikethrough wouldn't work in this case.

Comment: Thanks @DavyM, but how would I embed strikethrough within the code block using ``` or 4-space code blocks? My understanding is it will take my `<s></s>` as text and not parse it, hence my use of the `<pre><code></code></pre>`

Comment: Just never start a question with code, at all, ever. Begin with an introduction sentence to set context. When you run into a fellow coder at the coffee machine you don't start blurting lines of code at them, you give them just enough context to catch up on your issue.

Comment: I fail to see how the location of the code block relates to the issue of formatting. Regardless, if you look at the question I didn't :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, create a `<s>` tag and then inside it open a code block with three backticks ```

For instance

```
<s>
` ` `
e.on(‘state_changed’, function(new_state) {
    // Kill countForever
});

` ` `
</s>
```

Put the backticks ``` without spaces. This will solve the problem

Example

```
e.on(‘state_changed’, function(new_state) {
    // Kill countForever
});
```