# Unclear error message when trying to edit an answer

Tags: support, bug, edits, error-message

This seems like a bug to me. I do not know how to report a bug, that is why I'm writing here.

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Follow [Enumerate existing text in vim (make numbered list out of existing text)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32052756/enumerate-existing-text-in-vim-make-numbered-list-out-of-existing-text/66202153#answer-66202153)
- Start editing it
- Remove the blank line in the links' block in the end of the post: place cursor in the blank line right above `[ctrla]: ...` and press backspace
- Click outside the textbox to see the error.

**Problem**

It is impossible to understand what the problem is by reading that error. There is no rule that links have to have blank lines between them. I've spent half an hour to figure out what the problem is and left the post without links/code blocks at first.

[image: steps to reproduce]
[image: error message]

In case if browser version is relevant: `Version 88.0.4324.146 (Developer Build) built on Debian 10.7, running on Debian 10.8 (64-bit)`

Comment: _"I do not know how to report a bug, that is why writing here."_ If it's specific for Stack Overflow, you're in the right place. If it's network wide, it's better reported at [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: I rollbacked my edit anyway to keep this question relevant. But for the record, I didn't get any error after removing that blank line...

Comment: *It is impossible to understand what the problem is by reading that error.* Nor can we if you don't paste the exact error message as text in your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Images being interpreted as incorrectly formatted code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313967/11682469) or [“Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code” even if not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388255/11682469)

Comment: "following" the post seems irrelevant for this "issue", isn't it?

Comment: I can reproduce this issue when using an incognito tab (i.e. not being logged in). So if someone can't reproduce it, try to logout or use an incognito tab.

Comment: I guess the closest duplicate target is [Reference style markdown links being misidentified as code: “Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code.”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277896/11682469)

Comment: It would help more if your screenshot only contained 1) the links causing the error and 2) the error message. But as you can see from the links I posted, there are a lot of MSO posts about it already.

Comment: @JeanneDark I have edited steps to reproduce. All you need to do is 2 clicks and one keypress. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links have nothing to say about blank lines

Answer (score 7):

Well, that is somewhat unfortunate behavior (again) of the *is this post code* check.

Here is the analysis of what goes belly up in that post:

It does allow

```
[1]: https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#paragraph
[2]: https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#object-select
[3]: https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#CTRL-A
```

but it doesn't allow

```
[a]: https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#paragraph
[b]: https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#object-select
[c]: https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#CTRL-A
```

in that post.

The extra blank line was probably added to make the regex/parser behave.

Until this bug gets fixed:

Either leave the extra blank line in (that is an accepted workaround to put the parser on the right track) or replace the first anchor with a `1` but don't forget to also replace the reference up in the post as well.

Just note that inline code only needs one backtick, not two. The OP sprinkled those double backticks all over their post.

Please allow for [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) for an SE developer to untangle the regex mess and/or update the usage instructions on the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links)

Comment: Backtricks have no deal with an error appearance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links have not a single word about blank lines

Comment: So? What is your point?

Comment: Maybe “Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code.” needs its own FAQ, so many questions have been asked about it. :)

Comment: It is unexpected behavior, in other words it is a bug.

Comment: I didn't deny it wasn't a bug.

Comment: @JeanneDark I wouldn't oppose to having one. Feel free to start a faq-proposed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code section "Code spans" a bit below

Comment: @JeanneDark feel free to add custom tag to it